# Is there any way to directly query the in memory database used by Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-core

I'm using the in-memory database provider to do some tests of a .Net Core 2.2 application. I need to make one of the tables in the application inaccessible - either by renaming it or dropping it. Is there any way to run that kind of query against the in memory DB directly? I've tried to get the connection using:

```
context.Database.GetDbConnection();
```

but that throws an error

> Relational-specific methods can only be used when the context is using a relational database provider.

I am aware I can destroy the whole database with:

```
context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
```

but I need to retain it and only destroy or rename the one table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `InMemory` provider isn't backed by a relational database, and has a different set of operations that won't support your case.

You can instead use the SQLite in-memory mode ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite)), then create an interceptor that intercepts the issued EF commands, and either suppress the creation of the table, or suppress other queries targeted at that table.

```cs
public class MyInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor {
    public override InterceptionResult<int> NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result) {
        if (ContainsBannedTable(command)) {
            //suppress the operation
            result = InterceptionResult<int>.SuppressWithResult(0);
        }
        return base.NonQueryExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }

    private bool ContainsBannedTable(DbCommand command) {
        //or custom logic
        return command.CommandText.Contains("ToDeleteEntity");
    }
}
```

The following will throw an exception (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException... SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: ToDeleteEntity'`) when trying to access the undesired table.

```cs
var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
connection.Open();
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
                  .UseSqlite(connection)
                  .AddInterceptors(new MyInterceptor())
                  .Options
                  ;

var context = new MyContext(options);
context.Database.EnsureCreated();

context.AllowedEntity.Add(new AllowedEntity { Id = 1 });
context.SaveChanges();
Console.WriteLine(context.AllowedEntity.FirstOrDefault()?.Id); //1 - ok

context.ToDeleteEntity.Add(new ToDeleteEntity { Id = 1 });
//will throw an exception
context.SaveChanges();
Console.WriteLine(context.ToDeleteEntity.FirstOrDefault()?.Id);

//close the connection and clean up
//...
```

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext {
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {
    }

    public DbSet<AllowedEntity> AllowedEntity { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ToDeleteEntity> ToDeleteEntity { get; set; }
}

public class ToDeleteEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class AllowedEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```